# Import complete OSM data to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap

I've downloaded OSM data from geofabrik site and use below command to import OSM data to PostgreSQL.

```
osm2pgsql -c -d OSM --password -U postgres -H localhost -S E:\default.style E:\iran-latest.osm
```

command run properly without any problems. But after importing I can't find extra fields and attributes in relevant tables. Created tables are

```
planet_osm_point
planet_osm_line
planet_osm_polygon
planet_osm_roads
```

And planet_osm_point table has such columns

```
osm_id
z_order
way
```

where are the other attributes and columns?!
I need the other fields

Comment: I think that depends on the contents of your style file (https://osm2pgsql.org/doc/manual.html#style-file)

Comment: lan Turton tnx bro I got it

Comment: Do you mean that the problem is solved?

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://tipsforgis.wordpress.com/tag/osm2pgsql/) explains how to build an OSM database from the set of planet...tables that you have after import.  The tables (or osm objects) that  you end up with are determined by the SQl commands at this [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boundlessgeo/OSM/master/createDBobjects.sql). You can of course, edit that SQl so that you end up with the tables/attributes that you need.